# Insert temptable column into another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

TBMEMBER columns

```
id,name,employeeno,userno,amount1,amount2,type,status
```

TBDEDUCT columns

```
id,idno,employeeno,date,name,amount,status
```

TBITEMS

```
id,employeeno,userno,itemname,amount,status
```

SYNTAX

```
DECLARE memberlist CURSOR FOR SELECT id from TBMEMBER a where Status ='A' and Type = 'R' 
and employeeno not in (select EmployeeNo from TBRESIGN where  (txstatus='5' OR txstatus ='7' or txstatus='4') and EmployeeNo = a.EmployeeNo)

DECLARE @itemamt as decimal
select top 0 *
into #tempmember
from TBMEMBER

OPEN memberlist
    FETCH NEXT FROM memberlist
    INTO @id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #tempmember SELECT * FROM TBMEMBER where id =@id
        select @itemamt =  sum(amount) from TBITEMS where employeeno = #tempmember.employeeno and status = '9'
        insert into #TBDEDUCT values (#tempmember.userno,#tempmember.EmployeeNo,getdate(),#tempmember.name,#tempmember.amount1,'P')
        insert into #TBDEDUCT values (#tempmember.userno,#tempmember.EmployeeNo,getdate(),#tempmember.name,#tempmember.amount2,'P')
        insert into #TBDEDUCT values (#tempmember.userno,#tempmember.EmployeeNo,getdate(),#tempmember.name,#tempmember.@itemamt,'P')
        DELETE FROM #tempmember
    END
```

I'm trying to insert values into tbdeduct from temptable but it gives me an error:

```
The multi-part identifier "#tempmember.SLAIdNo" could not be bound.
```

Comment: I needed to insert 3 times per member with different values

Comment: Still, you do not need a cursor. Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: What are the structures of #tempmember and #tbdeduct?

Comment: Hi sir please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare variables for the other columns and assign them values in the `FETCH` statement. Use those variables in the `INSERT` statement instead of using the `table.columname`. However, you do not need to use a `CURSOR` for this. Here is one way:

```
WITH CteTBMember AS( -- Rows from your CURSOR
    SELECT tm.* 
    FROM TBMEMBER tm
    WHERE 
        tm.Status ='A'
        AND tm.Type = 'R' 
        AND tm.employeeno NOT IN (
            SELECT EmployeeNo 
            FROM TBRESIGN 
            WHERE 
                (txstatus='5' OR txstatus ='7' or txstatus='4')
                AND EmployeeNo = a.EmployeeNo
        )
)
INSERT INTO #TBDEDUCT
SELECT
    tm.idNo,
    tm.EmployeeNo,
    GETDATE(),
    tm.name,
    x.amount,
    'P'
FROM CTeTbMember tm
CROSS APPLY( -- 3 types of amount to be inserted
    SELECT tm.amount1 UNION ALL

    SELECT tm.amount2 UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM TBITEMS ti
    WHERE
        ti.employeeno = tm.employeeno
        AND ti.status = '9'
) x(amount);
```

Comment: How do I insert another cross apply with no source table? For example, I just want to change the 'P' value to 'U','S','P'